# Script that changes the ID of an element affects other elements two (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the ID of an DIV to collapse/expanded it and the approach I have works fine, until I add more than one of them. If I do, and I expand the first image, IsCollapsed will change to false, even though the first second image is still collapsed. This means the button has to be clicked twice. I know this is a logic problem but I can't think of a solution. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is a link to the actual thing: http://meet-cristian.com/Projects/webfaction.html

```
<script>
        var IsCollapsed = true;

        function Expand(ButtonID,CollapsedID,ExpandedID){
                if (IsCollapsed == true){
                        // IsCollapsed = false;
                        document.getElementById(CollapsedID).id = ExpandedID;
                        document.getElementById(ButtonID).innerText = '[-] Collapse Image';
                } else {
                        // IsCollapsed = true;
                        document.getElementById(ExpandedID).id = CollapsedID;
                        document.getElementById(ButtonID).innerText = '[+] Expand Image';
                }
        }
</script>


<div class="project-image" id="webfaction-03"></div>
<button type="button" class="expand" id="expand-01" onclick="Expand('expand-01', 'webfaction-03', 'webfaction-03-expanded'); IsCollapsed = !IsCollapsed;">[+] Expand Image</button>

<div class="project-image" id="webfaction-04"></div>
<button type="button" class="expand" id="expand-02" onclick="Expand('expand-02', 'webfaction-04', 'webfaction-04-expanded'); IsCollapsed = !IsCollapsed;">[+] Expand Image</button>
```

Comment: I'd use classes instead of IDs so it's flexible to add any number of images.

Comment: Wouldn't that expand all my images at once?

Comment: You need to pick the exact one that was clicked with js. I'm looking for a similar type of an implementation to share with you.

Comment: Your code works but there you should use `this` concept to achieve what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you will have to maintain `IsCollapsed` status for all the buttons. It could be done using maintaining a object having button IDs as keys.

```js
var ref = {};

function Expand(ButtonID, CollapsedID, ExpandedID) {
  if (typeof ref[ButtonID] === 'undefined') {
    ref[ButtonID] = true
  }
  if (ref[ButtonID] == true) {
    ref[ButtonID] = false;
    document.getElementById(CollapsedID).id = ExpandedID;
    document.getElementById(ButtonID).innerText = '[-] Collapse Image';
  } else {
    ref[ButtonID] = true;
    document.getElementById(ExpandedID).id = CollapsedID;
    document.getElementById(ButtonID).innerText = '[+] Expand Image';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="project-image" id="webfaction-03"></div>
<button type="button" class="expand" id="expand-01" onclick="Expand('expand-01', 'webfaction-03', 'webfaction-03-expanded');">[+] Expand Image</button>

<div class="project-image" id="webfaction-04"></div>
<button type="button" class="expand" id="expand-02" onclick="Expand('expand-02', 'webfaction-04', 'webfaction-04-expanded');">[+] Expand Image</button>
```

Comment: This makes sense. I had a feeling this was how I had to update my logic but it's literally the first JS script I wrote so I had no idea how to actually go about it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CristianMoisei – I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_